# Return same double only if the double is an int? (no decimals) Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, int, long-double

I'm using a `for-loop` to determine whether the `long double` is an int. I have it set up that the for loop loops another `long double` that is between 2 and `final`^1/2. `Final` is a loop I have set up that is basically 2 to the power of 2-10 minus 1. I am then checking if `final` is an integer. My question is how can I get only the `final` values that are integers?
My explanation may have been a bit confusing so here is my entire loop code. BTW I am using long doubles because I plan on increasing these numbers very largely.

```
for (long double ld = 1; ld<10; ld++) {
    long double final = powl(2, ld) - 1;
    //Would return e.g. 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63...etc.

    for (long double pD = 2; pD <= powl(final, 0.5); pD++) {
    //Create new long double
    long double newFinal = final / pD;
    //Check if new long double is int
    long int intPart = (long int)newFinal;
    long double newLong = newFinal - intPart;

    if (newLong == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Integer");
        //Return only the final ints?
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @nhgrif sorta has something.  You should be able to take the number, cast to long, cast back to double, and then compare the two bit-for-bit.  The only other thing you'd need to check is that the number of bits "used" in the long is fewer than the size of double's mantissa.

Comment: Oops -- I see you're using a `long double`, not casting between `long` and `double`.  Perhaps you could cast to a `long long`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast it to an int and subtract it from itself?

```
long double d;
//assign a value to d

int i = (int)d;
if((double)(d - i) == 0) {
    //d has no fractional part
}
```

---

As a note... because of the way floating point math works in programming, this `==` check isn't necessarily the best thing to do.  Better would be to decide on a certain level of tolerance, and check whether `d` was within that tolerance.

For example:

```
if(fabs((double)(d - i)) < 0.000001) {
    //d's fractional part is close enough to 0 for your purposes
}
```

---

You can also use `long long int` and `long double` to accomplish the same thing.  Just be sure you're using the right absolute value function for whatever type you're using:

- `fabsf(float)`
- `fabs(double)`
- `fabsl(long double)`

---

**EDIT...** Based on clarification of the actual problem... it seems you're just trying to figure out how to return a collection from a method.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)yourMethodName {
    NSMutableArray *retnArr = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(/*some loop logic*/) {
        // logic to determine if the number is an int

        if(/*number is an int*/) {
            [retnArr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:/*current number*/]];
        }
    }

    return retnArr;
}
```

Stick your logic into this method.  Once you've found a number you want to return, stick it into the array using the `[retnArr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:]];` method I put up there.

Once you've returned the array, access the numbers like this:

```
[[arrReturnedFromMethod objectAtIndex:someIndex] intValue];
```

Optionally, you might want to throw them into the `NSNumber` object as different types.

You can also use:

- `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:]`
- `[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:]`

And there are matching getters (`doubleValue`,`longLongValue`) to extract the number.  There are lots of other methods for `NSNumber`, but these seem the most likely you'd want to be using.

Comment: Sorry but I already have this. I may have been unclear in my explanation. I know how to figure if its an int or not. Because d changes, I want to return only the d's that are ints. Thank you for the advice on checking if its 0.

Comment: You're going to have to massively clarify where you're stuck.  The `if` will return true for any double that doesn't have a fractional part and `false` for a double that does.  Use that logic to do whatever you want now that it's sorting numbers out.

Comment: Ok I have A. A is a double that has been ran through a loop and is now the numbers 1, 3, 7, 15, 31...etc. I now want to take A within its loop and divide it by another double, B, that has been ran through a loop. That double is 2 through A to the power of 1/2. We now have A/B. I have set A/B to the double C. Because all these values are changing I just want to NSLOG C when C is an int. Clear?

Comment: Is this in a method?  You need to return a collection of numbers back to the caller?